# How to get LaTeX symbol rendering correctly in ipywidgets?

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have some code in Jupyter Lab which contains the 'infinity' symbol, coded as it would be in LaTeX. This symbol appears both in markdown and in printed text coming out of an ipywidgets slider description. This was working fine until I updated Jupyter packages last week, when the one on the slider description broke and does not display the symbol any more.

I have now updated ipywidgets as well but the problem persists. I read somewhere that jupyter implements Mathjax to show symbols like this, but somehow this is not carrying across to my slider. Has ipywidgets dropped support for symbols?

This is my code and how it is behaving now:

**Markdown code and rendering: **

### Set U$\infty$

[image of markdown] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ru0Z.png)

**ipywidgets code and (non-)rendering:**

```
U_infinity = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=20,
    min=0,
    max=200,
    step=1,
    description='U$\infty$ (m/s) :',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)
```

display (U_infinity)

[image of slider with infinity symbol not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA8yj.png)

Comment: No need to ask the question in the title as your code should work; this is a known issue that has arisen recently, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/latex-not-always-typeset-in-ipywidgets-in-jupyter-lab/19379/3?u=fomightez) and [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3848). There should be a fix coming as stated [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/latex-not-always-typeset-in-ipywidgets-in-jupyter-lab/19379/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I did try looking for answers but obviously searched for the wrong thing :)